# Determine AppBarLayout previous state

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

How can i get the previous state of an `AppBarLayout`? Because when the current state becomes `IDLE` the behavior will be different if it comes from `COLLAPSED` state or `EXPANDED` one.

For now i am able to know the current state thanks to `AppBarStateChangeListener` :

```
   appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state) {
            switch (state) {
                case COLLAPSED:
                    //do stuff when COLLAPSED
                    break;
                case EXPANDED:
                    //do stuff when EXPANDED
                    break;
                case IDLE:
                    //do stuff when IDLE
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

If you have a trick to do that, you will really help me.

Thanks

Comment: Keep old stete in variable